# Sending Assets to Android wear

Tags: android, wear-os

I have problem syncing assets with the *Wear.DataApi*.


When I try to send String, long, int, etc... using the *Wear.DataApi* everyting runs fine. The problem is when I load an Asset into the *PutDataMapRequest* object. The image loads fine but it isn't transferred to the Wear device, even though I put the current **timestamp** in order for the *DataItem* to be different every time. 


Here is my code:


**Phone**

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
            .addApi(Wearable.API)
            .build()
```

```
public void sendImage(){
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.image);
    Asset asset = createAssetFromBitmap(bitmap);
    PutDataMapRequest dataMap = PutDataMapRequest.create("/image");
    dataMap.getDataMap().putAsset("profileImage", asset);
    dataMap.getDataMap().putLong("timestamp", System.currentTimeMillis());
    PutDataRequest request = dataMap.asPutDataRequest();
    request.setUrgent();
    Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem(mGoogleApiClient, request);

    Log.d(TAG, "Image set for sending");
}

private Asset createAssetFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    final ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteStream);
    return Asset.createFromBytes(byteStream.toByteArray());
}
```

**Watch**

```
@Override
public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEventBuffer) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Data has changed");

    for (DataEvent event : dataEventBuffer) {
        if (event.getType() == DataEvent.TYPE_CHANGED &&
                event.getDataItem().getUri().getPath().equals("/image")) {
            DataMapItem dataMapItem = DataMapItem.fromDataItem(event.getDataItem());
            Asset profileAsset = dataMapItem.getDataMap().getAsset("profileImage");
            Bitmap bitmap = loadBitmapFromAsset(profileAsset);

            // Do something with the bitmap
            ImageView image = (ImageView) mContext.findViewById(R.id.image);
            image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            Log.d(TAG, "Bitmap OK, Loaded");
        }
    }
}
```

It works when I put no Assets. So, where's the problem? Am I missing something

Comment: I ran into similar issues. Apparently there are some issues with the `DataLayerApi` causing it to fail syncing correctly, I ended up switching to using just the `MessageApi`.

Comment: MessageApi won't work for me, since it has limited size and I'm transferring large images, which are 1MB+.

Comment: I know it isn't the nicest solution, but you could compress the image using a `ByteArrayOutputStream`. Then get the byte array and break it up using `Arrays.copyOfRange`, and send it in multiple messages. Pain in the neck, I know, but if no one gives you a better answer, it would at least work.

Comment: Can you explain why you need to transfer 1MB+ images to the watch? Even an _uncompressed_ `ARGB_8888` `Bitmap` at 320x320 px (the most common Wear screen size) would be less than 400k.

Comment: I need full res photos. My gallery app is built on the idea of zooming the photos.

Comment: OK, fair enough. One other question, then: can you add your `createAssetFromBitmap` code to the question? Or is it just the code from http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/assets.html?

Comment: It's the code from the official Android training. I'll add it anyways.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Given you're sending photos, you can get a **lot** better compression by using JPEG rather than PNG:

```
private Asset createAssetFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    final ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, byteStream);
    return Asset.createFromBytes(byteStream.toByteArray());
}
```

Adjust the compression rate (second parameter to the `compress` method) to suit your needs.

Or, if you're starting with JPEG files already on storage, you can just read them straight into a `ByteArray`. Here's code I use for doing that:

```
RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(filename.toString(), "r");
byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
file.read(bytes);
Asset myAsset = Asset.createFromBytes(bytes);
```

Either way, that should get your `Asset` small enough to transfer reliably.

And if it doesn't... the [WearCompanionLibrary](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-WearCompanionLibrary) has sample code for sending files using the Channel API. It's a completely different alternative to the Data API.

Comment: Well, I don't think it's a problem with the code you've posted. I just compared it line-by-line with some of my own that's working with `Asset`s, and it looks fine. So presumably, the problem is elsewhere; you could try unpairing and re-pairing the watch to clear the Data API's storage, or switching to the Channel API as I mentioned.

Comment: The problem was fixed by restarting the devices and clearing cache.